# jQuery dialog not showing in windows 7 IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

would appreciate some helps with why jQuery dialog is not showing on this page. http://neenahgirlsbbc.com in Windows7, IE9. It works with IE8, Firefox, & Chrome. I've tried different Doctypes and metatags but I just can't get it to work. The icon is "For Parents" and should show a dialog when clicked. I've looked at other questions concerning this same issue and tried suggestions but nothing is working. Can someone maybe please see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, try looking at the output of the w3c validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fneenahgirlsbbc.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Unless you changed something I can open your site and the dialog when clicking the `for parents` logo perfectly fine in IE9 on windows 7. However, when I set my IE9 to IE8 browser mode the dialog does not show. It would really help if you post the relevant code. The html and the script which binds the click event to the logo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a lot of unmatched HTML tags, that's probably part of what is causing you problems, my recomendation, take a look at your browser's developer utilities, for IE, press F12 and they will show up. Take a look at the Javascript debbuger and you will see the exact lines that are marked as unmatched tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. The paged worked in IE9 quirks mode (compatibility view) which indicated the issue was with the jQuery script/plugin. Apparently, jQuery plugins are notorious for being outdated in terms of browser hacks that are not filtered for newer browsers. So, I had to use an older version and then it worked.